# Server not letting me read from filestream

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream

I have been trying to figure out this error for days now and I still don't understand what is happening

```
public async Task<int> UploadToDatabase_Data(VideoPresenterFile file, DatabaseConnectionObject connObj)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder WriteData_Builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        WriteData_Builder.InitialCatalog = connObj.Database;
        WriteData_Builder.IntegratedSecurity = connObj.isIntegratedSecurityEnabled;
        WriteData_Builder.DataSource = connObj.IP;
        WriteData_Builder.AsynchronousProcessing = connObj.isAsyncEnabled;

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            using (SqlConnection WriteData_Connection = new SqlConnection(WriteData_Builder.ToString()))
            {
                await WriteData_Connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                SqlCommand WriteData_Command = new SqlCommand();
                WriteData_Command.Connection = WriteData_Connection;
                WriteData_Command.CommandText = "SELECT Video.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() FROM VideoLibrary.dbo.Library WHERE Name = 'temp'";
                //WriteData_Command.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = file.Name;

                SqlTransaction WriteData_Transaction = WriteData_Connection.BeginTransaction("UploadDataTransaction");
                WriteData_Command.Transaction = WriteData_Transaction;

                using (SqlDataReader WriteData_TransactionReader = WriteData_Command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    await WriteData_TransactionReader.ReadAsync();
                    string WriteData_SqlPath = WriteData_TransactionReader.GetString(0);
                    byte[] WriteData_TransactionContext = WriteData_TransactionReader.GetSqlBytes(1).Value;

                    using (SqlFileStream WriteData_FileStream = new SqlFileStream(WriteData_SqlPath, WriteData_TransactionContext, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        int count = 20 * 1024 * 1024, offset = 0;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[count];

                        FileInfo file_FileInfo = new FileInfo(file.Path);
                        FileStream file_FileStream = new FileStream(file_FileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                        do
                        {
                            await file_FileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
                            await WriteData_FileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count);
                            offset += count;

                        } while (offset <= file_FileInfo.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The code is executed smoothly all the way to this line:

```
using (SqlFileStream WriteData_FileStream = new SqlFileStream(WriteData_SqlPath, WriteData_TransactionContext, FileAccess.Write))
```

Then the error comes.

*The Error:* **An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The user name or password is incorrect
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.**

I can add insert a row with every necessary detail. When I am adding a whole row I do not use **TransactionScope** and **TransactionContext**  but when I try to read or write something specifically to the file stream I'm using the Scope and Context, and it throws that error.

What I have tried:

I Tried recreating the table and the whole database

I tried reinstalling SQL Server Express

I tried add features to Windows, particularly *Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web
Services -> Security -> Windows Authentication/Basic Authentication*

I tried manipulating the rights of the user I am using but it is a dbo so there should be no problem.

I tried running the same code on a different machine (With the same Microsoft account)*

**I know that FileStream is working only with Windows Authentication and I am using windows 8 so everything is the same (or at least should be) in terms of accounts**

Comment: What user is running the application pool in IIS?

Comment: Why ISS, I am not creating a services so I haven't had the need to install ISS